# Changing ordering of results in django-haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using django-haystack for search. By default it is showing oldest objects first whereas i want to show latest on top. Can anyone guide me how can i do this?
My code sample is shown below:

#### search_indexes.py

```
class PostIndex(indexes.RealTimeSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    created = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='created')
 
    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(created__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Can anyone tell me the exact file where i'll have to make changes and what changes? Do i have to make changes to query.py file in haystack? Query.py has

```
 def order_by(self, *args):
        """Alters the order in which the results should appear."""
        clone = self._clone()

        for field in args:
            clone.query.add_order_by(field)
        
        return clone
```

How can i make changes to this to show the latest on the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [order_by](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=order_by#SearchQuerySet.order_by) in your haystack_urls.py (or whatever you called it) e.g

```
qs = SearchQuerySet().order_by('-created')

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', SearchView(searchqueryset=qs), name='haystack_search'),
)
```